# Экранирование символов от 1 до 126

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, markdown

В TelegramAPI,в разделе с документацией по MarkdownV2
Так вот,там есть строчка

> Any character with code between 1 and 126 inclusively can be escaped anywhere with a preceding '\' character

Так вот,как я понял,нужно экранировать символы от 1 до 126,но вот как это сделать - я не знаю.Может есть какой-нибудь удобный способ?

Comment: может, вам будет проще использовать html-style? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style

Comment: В приведенной цитате нет слова "нужно". Есть слово "можно".